# Проблема с авторизацией pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql

В графическом режиме PostgreSQL 9.6 нажимаю подключиться к серверу и выводится " Please enter the password for the user 'postgres' to connect the server - "PostgreSQL 9.6" " и строка для ввода пароля. 
Как мне зайти под другим пользователем? Другой пользователь уже создан на этом же сервере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашла способ, вдруг кому-то понадобится.
Дисконнектить нужный сервер, пкм на сервере и в свойствах изменить имя пользователя.